# Accessing values of e.ClickedItem object from C# GridView on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building a Windows Phone 8.1 App for a client and have run into something I can't source an answer for, hence the question. I apologize in advance as it's probably something obvious and I'm oblivious to it.

I have a GridView bound to a vendor list from my data model. I can select / click a returned value from the Grid as planned. 
**XAML extract:**

```
<GridView x:Name="VendorsGridView" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Margin="10,8,10,12"
              Foreground="White"     
              SelectionMode="Single"
              IsSwipeEnabled="False"
              ItemClick="VendorsGridView_ItemClick"
              IsItemClickEnabled="True"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VendorTemplate}">
    </GridView>

</Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrVendor}" 
                           Name="VNo"
                           Grid.Row="0"
                           Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Top"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           FontSize="18"
                           FontWeight="SemiBold"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StrVName}" 
                           Name="VName"
                           Grid.Row="1"
                           Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           FontSize="14"/>
```

If I examine e.ClickedItem in the debug window I can see the value I am trying to find, (StrVendor or vendor number). The design is then to write this back to a static table for use as a default when looking at other data.

**Debug Window Output:**

```
e.ClickedItem
{MOQ_v301.ViewModel.VendorViewModel}
base: {MOQ_v301.ViewModel.VendorViewModel}
IsDirty: true
isDirty: true
StrVendor: "40520"
strVendor: "40520"
StrVName: "Forest Garden PLC"
strVName: "Forest Garden PLC"
```

My question is how can I get the vendor number captured to a string variable to achieve it?

Comment: Because your grid is bound to a model, you are getting 1 item of that model back through the click. So just cast that item to the model and get the Vender number... Not sure what the actual model class is but assuming it's VendorViewModel the code should be: ((VendorViewModel)e.ClickedItem).StrVendor this will give you the actual vendor number.

Comment: Thanks Depechie, great answer - really clear and on point.

Comment: hmm seems I aswered it through a comment :D, I'll repost it in an aswer so you can accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because your grid is bound to a model, you are getting 1 item of that model back through the click. So just cast that item to the model and get the Vender number... Not sure what the actual model class is but assuming it's VendorViewModel the code should be: ((VendorViewModel)e.ClickedItem).StrVendor this will give you the actual vendor number.

Best to check if you are actually getting a model so the final code could be as following:

```
if(e.ClickedItem is VendorViewModel)
{
   var vendornr = ((VendorViewModel)e.ClickedItem).StrVendor;
}
```